# Inkscape problems with special characters

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape I recently encountered a problem with special characters.
When I want to type special characters like é, è, I get Cyrillic letters instead.
Even when I copy and paste from text (both from within the same doc as from another document) that is displayed correctly, the pasted letters convert into Cyrillic.
For instance the é turns into и.
I cannot find anything settings that could be the cause (or possible solution). Also my keyboard is not set to Russian/Cyrillic.

In the past I never had this problem. I am using Inkscape .48 on a Dutch Windows 8.1.

Some advise would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the font I am using, it seems to be a Cyrillic (ABengaly) font. Changing the font solves the problem

(I am surprised I did not face this problem before, apparently I managed to avoid the combo of this font and the French language up until now.)